# How to validate without request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to validate an array but without a request.
In laravel docs validation is described like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

But I can't use  $request because the data comes from an external api and the validation is not inside a controller. How can I validate this array? For example:

```
$validatedData = validate([
    'id' => 1,
    'body' => 'text'
], [
    'id' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by create request object like so:

```
$request = new Request([
    'id' => 1,
    'body' => 'text'
]);

$this->validate($request, [
    'id' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required'
]);
```

and thus you will get all the functionality of the Request class

Comment: You don't need request object to validate Array.

Comment: At least in Lumen, it must be a Request object. `Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Controller::validate(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\\Http\\Request, array given`

Answer (score 17):

Should be. Because `$request->all()` hold all input data as an array .

```
$input = [
    'title' => 'testTitle',
    'body' => 'text'
];
```

$input is your custom array.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 16):

Validator::make expects array and not a request object.
You can pass any array and implements the rules on it.

```
Validator::make(['name' => 'Tom'], ['name' => 'required', 'id' => 'required']);
```

And it will validate the array. So $request object is not necessary.

Comment: Great answer! Sad to see people usig hacks to "fix" their code.

Answer (score 4):

`$request->all()` is array not request object. 
This code will work:

```
$data = [
    'id' => 1,
    'body' => 'text'
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'id' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also merge data with the request object:

```
$data = ['id' => 1];
$request->merge($data);
```

Then validate as per usual.