# Laravel Validator::make is being ignored

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a random string with the length of 8 using `Str::random()` and then use validator to check whether the created string satisfied the conditions or not

Since the string is generated inside the function. I think the Request object is not required (also this question [How to validate without request in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827068/how-to-validate-without-request-in-laravel) strengthen the point) so I did go with

```
$random_str = Str::random(8);
$validator = Validator::make(['random_str' => $random_str], [
    'random_str' => 'min:9',
]

if (!validator) {
    Log::info('validation failed');
    return [];
}
```

Since the `$random_str` length is 8, I expect the validator to fail but it didn't. When I try the Request object, it works as expected.

```
$random_str = Str::random(8);
$request = new Request([
    'random_str' => $random_str
]);
$validator = $request->validate([
    'random_str' => 'min:9',
]

if (!validator) {
    Log::info('validation failed');
    return [];
}
```

Comment: `$request->validate` works because Laravel is implicitly doing the job for you for validating and redirecting back to the form page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using Validator::make(), don't forget to call fails() to check if the validation has failed.
Use this

```
$random_str = Str::random(8);
$validator = Validator::make(['random_str' => $random_str], [
    'random_str' => 'min:9',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    Log::info('Validation failed');
    return [];
}
```